# A question about sigma algebras and generators on the extended real line

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

We define the extended real line $\bar R = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\} \cup \{\infty\} $ The Borel sets $\beta(\bar R) = \sigma([-\infty, x]), x\in \mathbb{R}$. We want to show that  $\beta(\bar R)$ can also be generated by $(x,\infty], x\in \mathbb{R}.$

That is we want to show $\sigma([-\infty, x]_{x \in \mathbb{R}}) = \sigma((x, \infty]_{x \in \mathbb{R}})$. To do this we need to show:

1) $[-\infty, x] \subset \sigma((x, \infty]_{x \in \mathbb{R}})$ and 2) $(x, \infty] \subset \sigma([-\infty, x]_{x \in \mathbb{R}})$.

We know that $(x, \infty] \subset \sigma((x, \infty]_{x \in \mathbb{R}})$ and $[-\infty, x] \subset \sigma([-\infty, x]_{x \in \mathbb{R}})$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @njguliyev Okay great, thanks for confirming. Any ideas on what kind of approach I could take to show 1) or 2)?

Comment: Well, you've introduced the notation, but if the intention is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all rays of the sort $(x,\infty]$, then certainly, $x$ is whichever (and all) real number. Hint: for a given $x$, what's the relation between $[-\infty,x]$ and $(x,\infty]$?

Comment: @JonathanY. The union of those two sets is the extended real line! Let me think about how we can use that here. We know $\bar R$ has to be in $\sigma ((x, \infty])$.

Comment: What you can do to avoid your confusion in using one free and one bounded occurence of $x$ is writing, say, $\sigma(\{(x,\infty]\mid x \in \mathbb R\})$ as $\sigma(\{(y,\infty]\mid y \in \mathbb R\})$ which is exactly the same set.

Comment: I think a less confusing way of writing the above is $\sigma(\{ [-\infty, y] \}_{y \in \mathbb{R}})$.

Comment: Bingo! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma_l =\sigma(\{ [-\infty, y] \}_{y \in \mathbb{R}})$, $\Sigma_r =\sigma(\{ (y, \infty] \}_{y \in \mathbb{R}})$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then  $[-\infty,x] \in \Sigma_l$, and since $\Sigma_l$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, we have $\overline{\mathbb{R}} \setminus [-\infty,x] = (x,\infty] \in \Sigma_l$. Hence $\{ (x,\infty] \}_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \subset \Sigma_l$, and so $\Sigma_r \subset \Sigma_l$.

A similar argument shows the reverse inequality.

Comment: Can you clarify how do we know $[-\infty, x] \in \Sigma _{l}$? I know that $\Sigma_l$ is the minimal sigma-algebra containing ${[-\infty,y]}_{y \in \mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Actually I got it, writing it as $\{[-\infty, y]\}_{y \in \mathbb{R}}$ makes a lot more sense :).